# Web scraping Indeed, can't get full job description, python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need your help. When scraping Indeed getting not a full job description, jobs need to be expanded to see the whole job description. I have no idea how to fix it. Help, please.

Thank you in advance,

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


class JobInformation:
def __init__(self):
    self.job_information = []
    self.job_information_dict = {}

def get_data(self):
    for i in range(50):
        id = 10
        URL ='https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=%22cable+technician%22&radius=25&sort=date{id}'
        page = requests.get(URL)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        job_elements = soup.find_all(class_="jobsearch-SerpJobCard")

        for job_element in job_elements:
            job_title = job_element.find('a', class_='jobtitle')
            job_company = job_element.find(class_="company")
            job_summary = job_element.find(class_='summary')
            job_location = job_element.find(class_='location')
            job_date_posted = job_element.find(class_='date')

            self.job_information_dict = {
                'title': job_title.text.strip(),
                'company': job_company.text.strip(),
                'summary': job_summary.text.strip(),
                'location': job_location.text.strip(),
                'date': job_date_posted.text.strip(),
            }
            self.job_information.append(self.job_information_dict)

        f = open('jobinfo.csv', 'w')
        fieldnames = ['title', 'company',
                      'summary', 'location', 'date']

        with f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()

            for self.data in self.job_information:
                writer.writerow(self.data)

    print("Writing to csv successful...")
    id = +10


ji = JobInformation()

ji.get_data()
```

Comment: I encountered the same problem. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I am just adding this incase you didn't know but scraping Indeed.com is against their TOS, see https://www.indeed.com/legal?hl=en&redirect=true "Use of any automated system or software, whether operated by a third party or otherwise, to extract data from the Site (such as screen scraping or crawling) is prohibited".

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to get the partial URL for each job post with `job_element.h2.a.get('href')`

Combine that with the server URL you can go to a specific job post. For example:

```
jobURL = "http://indeed.com" + job_element.h2.a.get('href')
```

However, you'll need to send a new HTTP request for each job post, but you can get the full job description from there.